# Problem with UDF in Spark - TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

*Hello everyone!* 
I have a dataframe with **2510765 rows** containing application reviews with relative score and having the following structure:

```
root
 |-- content: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: string (nullable = true)
```

I wrote these two functions, to remove punctuation and remove emojis from text:

```
import string

def remove_punct(text):
    return text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

and

```
import re

def removeEmoji(text):
    regrex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
    return regrex_pattern.sub(r'',text)
```

I use the **`udf`** function to create a spark function starting from the ones I defined for the removal of punctuation and emojis:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

punct_remove = udf(lambda s: remove_punct(s))

removeEmoji = udf(lambda s: removeEmoji(s))
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-29-e5d42d609b59> in <module>()
----> 1 new_df = new_df.withColumn("content", remove_punct(df_merge["content"]))
      2 new_df.show(5)

<ipython-input-21-dee888ef5b90> in remove_punct(text)
      2 
      3 def remove_punct(text):
----> 4     return text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
      5 
      6 

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

How can it be solved? Is there another way to make user-written functions run on the dataframe? 
**Thank you ;)**

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace suggests that you are calling the python method directly, not the udf.

`remove_punct` is a plain vanilla Python function while `punct_remove` is a udf that can be used as second parameter of the `withColumn` call.

One way to solve the problem is to use `punct_remove` instead of `remove_punct` in the `withColumn` call.

Another way to reduce the chance of mixing up the Python function with the udf is to use the `@udf` annotation:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

@F.udf(returnType=T.StringType())
def remove_punct(text):
    return text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

df.withColumn("content", remove_punct(F.col("content"))).show()
```